# How to dynamically create a class name within Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Salutation Guys,

Im trying to create a class from the variables data-target within the js file. It has to be done with the data- attribute. I'm trying to create 'box^' on the fly with the data- attribute.

```js
var event = "data-event";
var css = "data-css";
var target = "data-target";
var properties = "data-properties";

$(".javascript").on('input', function() {
  $('.box1').css($(this).attr(css), $(this).val());
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: teal;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box2 {
  background: navy;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box box1"> </div>
<div class="box box2"> </div>

<input data-event="on" data-properties="css" data-css="opacity" data-target="box1" type="range" min="0" max="1" step=".01" class="javascript" value="0" />

<input data-event="on" data-properties="css" data-css="opacity" data-target="box2" type="range" min="0" max="1" step=".01" class="javascript" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit hard to understand what you are after here, it looks as if you are attempting to access the data properties of a html element, to do that you use .data()

So for your code I think you will need

```
$(".javascript").on('input', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $('.' + $this.data('target')).css($this.data('css'), $this.val());
});
```

Comment: I would up vote you, but it says Im new and I have to unlock it by being more active on the site.

Comment: That's fine,  I believe you can still accept it as the answer, that would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I have one more question. Is it possibe to create a var = data-properties="css". That way I can change out the .css with lets say .text or .addClass?

Comment: In your html code change data-properties="css" to data-properties="style" then replace .css($this.data('css'), $this.val()); with .attr($this.data('properties'), $this.data('css') + ': ' + $this.val() + ';');

Comment: It works… but how will it change from .css to .innerHeight, .offset(), or .scrollLeft() dynamically from a data- attribute?

Comment: Oh, in that case no it will not work. Sorry I can;t come up with a solution to your second issue at the moment.

Comment: ok… thank you for your help, you solved the big problem. The second one was just an add on.